# Docker - extended options for docker image purge

Tags: docker

I am not able to find the way to delete a certain Docker Image using the IMAGE ID and  I can't figure it out from the Docker Documentation.

the syntax is: `docker image prune --filter "label=key=value"`

**How can I delete image with ID=24de51a55d98 (second image) from the output below?**

```
root@ubuntu:/home/vg/proj# docker image ls

REPOSITORY           TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE

vbgtest2018/node_p   latest    0eca292619dd   17 minutes ago   174MB

**None               None    24de51a55d98   23 minutes ago   170MB**

node                 alpine    025c3cbb849f   11 days ago      169MB
```

Comment: [`docker rmi IMAGE`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rmi/)

Comment: ... or using the long explicit command `docker image rm IMAGE`. See `docker image --help` and `docker image rm --help`. `IMAGE` is either a `name[:tag]` or an id.

Answer (score 1):

use `docker rmi` command.
rmi - remove image

```
docker rmi [OPTIONS] IMAGE [IMAGE...]
```

in your case-

```
docker rmi 24de51a55d98
```

or even you can use

```
docker rmi -f 24de51a55d98
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with this command -

```
docker image rm {image-id} -f
```

In you case

```
docker image rm 24de51a55d98 -f
```